# C++ catch error and exit the function

Tags: c++, templates, error-handling

I use try{} catch(){} to handle errors in a function which return a template type.

```
 T get (int iOffset) const
    {
        try {
            checkIndex(iOffset);
        }
        catch (char const* msg) {
            std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        }
        int index = (m_iReadIdx + iOffset) % m_iBuffLength;
        float  a = m_ptBuff[index];
        return a;
    }
```

The function would first call `checkIndex` to check whether the input is out of range and throw an error if so.

However, I don't want the outside `get` return any value if `checkIndex` throws an error, because the returned value may be used by other functions or printed out incorrectly. If I put a return in the catch block, I don't know what to return since it's a template. If I don't, the codes following the catch block will still get executed and therefore return a value.

Is there any way to do that? I'm new to C++ and wondering how people usually do the error handling in this condition? THanks!

Comment: Just do not catch that exception, or throw new one

Comment: OT: don’t throw a char*. Always throw something derived from std::exception. Catch as const &. Use std::runtime_error to get an exception that handles a std::string message.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I don't want the outside get return any value if checkIndex throws an error, because the returned value may be used by other functions or printed out incorrectly.

You can always re-throw the exception after logging

```
T get (int iOffset) const
{
    try {
        checkIndex(iOffset);
    }
    catch (char const* msg) {
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        throw; // Just re-throw the exception
    }
    int index = (m_iReadIdx + iOffset) % m_iBuffLength;
    float  a = m_ptBuff[index];
    return a;
}
```

Comment: if I re-throw an exception, it seems the error message `msg` won't be printed out? In the end, there would be an unhandled exception. How can I get the `msg` showed?

Comment: @YongliangHe Try printing to `std::cerr` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use optional for this situation. One of idea of this construct was to indicate that value cannot be set correctly because of some mistakes.

```
std::optional< T > get (int iOffset ) const
    {
        try {
            checkIndex(iOffset);
        }
        catch (char const* msg) {
            std::cout << msg << std::endl;
            return std::optional< T >();
        }
        int index = (m_iReadIdx + iOffset) % m_iBuffLength;
        float  a = m_ptBuff[index];
        return return std::optional< T >( a );
    }
```

Using of such function can look like this:

```
auto result = get( someOffset );
if( result )
{
  // correct, processing result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way is first to decide: What exactly should your get() return if it cannot return the 'proper' value?
In many cases it is just 0, or -1, or some other special value. 
And then the code become very simple:

```
 T get (int iOffset) const
    {
        T a;
        try {
            checkIndex(iOffset);
            int index = (m_iReadIdx + iOffset) % m_iBuffLength;
            a = m_ptBuff[index];
        }
        catch (char const* msg) {
            a = special_value_for_errors;
            std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a value from a buffer with this particular offset, so I'm afraid returning any `special_value_for_errors` may be misleading? As the value stored in buffer might be equal to `special_value_for errors' by accident?